# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Puzzling breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6        127
Users destroyed                                 694          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Users contacted                                   9          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            99      3,336
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                9        561
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         64      2,773
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               10        336
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                61      3,210
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               51      2,476
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          2
Questions reopened                               26         20
Questions protected                               8         44
Questions migrated                                2          2
Questions flagged⁴                               16      3,353
Questions closed                                274        473
Question flags handled⁴                         392      2,977
Posts unlocked                                    2          5
Posts undeleted                                  14        255
Posts locked                                      5        455
Posts deleted⁵                                  456      2,008
Posts bumped                                      0         83
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               14          0
Comments flagged                                635      1,790
Comments deleted⁶                             1,799      4,881
Comment flags handled                         1,378      1,047
Answers flagged                                  57      2,027
Answer flags handled                            602      1,482
All comments on a post moved to chat              6          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: On that note, I have flagged this for moderator attention, as it is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. :-) Happy new year!